# Select elements in named vector

Tags: r, vector, statistics

I'm a begginer with R and I can't figure out how to do this:

I have a named vector with player names and his score:

```
x <-c(3, 4, 6, 2, 3, 5, 0, 1, 1, 2)
names(x) <- c("ALBERTO", "ANTONIO", "PEPE", "JUAN", "ANDRES", "PEDRO", "MARCOS", "MATEO", "JAVIER", "FRANCISCO")
```

What I need is to get the scores for the players which name starts with letter "A".

Is it possible to set a condition on the element name?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

One way is

```
x[grepl("^A", names(x))]
# ALBERTO ANTONIO  ANDRES 
#       3       4       3
```

`^` stands for beginning of the string in regex. `grepl` will return a logical vector which will allow to index out of `x`

Or (as pointed in comments) you could avoid regex and do

```
x[substr(names(x), 1, 1) == 'A']
```